# Unable to list all repositories in Git Enterprise

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am using below command to list all the repositories but it is not giving me more than 10 repos

```
curl --insecure -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://my-gitserver.com/api/v3/orgs/my-org/repos?per_page=100  | grep  'html_url' | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/,//g' | sort | uniq -u
```

What would be the correct command to list all the repos in my Organization?

Comment: you could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) json parser instead of grep/awk/sed

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/troubleshooting#not-all-results-returned

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D+list+all+the+repositories

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER :

Below command worked for me :

curl --silent --insecure -H "Authorization: token ${TOKEN} " https://mygitserver.com/api/v3/orgs/myorg-ops/repos?per_page=500 | grep '"name"' | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/,//g' | sort | uniq -u > repos.txt